# I add file to my API and got invalid character '-' in numeric literal in POST API

Tags: go, go-gin

I know this code need to send a JSON instead of form data in the API

```
err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&modelAdd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

But I need to add file, is there anything like ShouldBindJSON but for FormData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ShouldBind` to get data from form data as the documentation says

https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation

Comment: I need to add form to the struct, thank you! it's working